# Threejs Line2 fails toJson() serialization

Tags: json, serialization, three.js

I am adding a Line2 in Threejs (v 146)

```
  const lineGeometry = new LineGeometry();
  const line2Points = [10, 10, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0];
  lineGeometry.setPositions(line2Points);
  const matLine = new LineMaterial({
    color: 0xe3e1e1,
    worldUnits: true,
    linewidth: 0.3,
    dashed: false,
    alphaToCoverage: false,
    transparent: false,
    opacity: 1,
    depthWrite: false,
    depthTest: false,
  });
const line = new Line2(lineGeometry, matLine);
line.toJSON();
```

Calling `line.toJSON();` causes this error to pop:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at extractFromCache (three.module.js:8296:5)
    at Line2.toJSON (three.module.js:8263:23)
```

It can also be easily reproduced in the official example:
https://threejs.org/examples/?q=line#webgl_lines_fat by adding a `line.toJSON();` call at line 123

Any idea how the serialization can be achieved? Or if this is a bug/missing feature of Line2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue of `LineGeometry`, this geometry just don't have a `toJSON()` method to serialize itself, i guess it is a bug.